# Optimize AD search - get group members

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

Is it possible to query only those members of group, which is also group from AD?

Now I am using following code:

```
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, identityType, domainGroup);
if (null != group)
{
    var subGroups = group.GetMembers().Where(g => g is GroupPrincipal).Select(g => g.Name);
................
}
```

The problem is that my group has a big amount of users (more than 50 000), as a result the query works extremely long. Also, big amount of data is transferred.

How can I query only direct sub groups (not users) in a single request?

**EDIT**

I ended up with `DirectorySearcher`. Here is my completed code:

```
using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(string.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(memberof={0}))", group.DistinguishedName), new[] { "cn" }))
{
    searcher.PageSize = 10000;
    var results = SafeFindAll(searcher);

    foreach (SearchResult result in results)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Properties["cn"].Count; i++)
        {
            subGroups.Add((string)result.Properties["cn"][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the performance increase you're seeing?

Comment: @X3074861X, performance depends on how many users group has. Query above allows we to skip user selection because I request groups only, as a result for some groups performance increases greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the the lower level `DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace instead of `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` for something like this.

The problem I've had (along with many others) with the `AccountManagement` libraries is the lack of customization and configuration. That being said, this is how I search through Active Directory, making use of `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope` as well.

```
//Define the connection
var ldapidentifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ServerName, port);
var ldapconn = new LdapConnection(ldapidentifier, credentials);

//Set some session options (important if the server has a self signed cert or is transferring over SSL on Port 636)
ldapconn.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
ldapconn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;

//Set the auth type, I'm doing this from a config file, you'll probably want either Simple or Negotatie depending on the way your directory is configured.
ldapconn.AuthType = config.LdapAuth.LdapAuthType;
```

This is where `DirectoryServices` really starts to shine. You can easily define a filter to search by a particular group or subgroup. You could do something like this :

```
string ldapFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectclass=user)(memberOf=CN=All Europe,OU=Global,dc=company,dc=com)";  

//Create the search request with the domain, filter, and SearchScope. You'll most likely want Subtree here, but you could possibly use Base as well. 
var getUserRequest = new SearchRequest(Domain, ldapFilter, SearchScope.Subtree)                                        

//This is crucial in getting the request speed you want. 
//Setting the DomainScope will suppress any refferal creation during the search
var SearchControl = new SearchOptionsControl(SearchOption.DomainScope);
getUserRequest.Controls.Add(SearchControl);

//Now, send the request, and get your array of Entry's back
var Response = (SearchResponse)ldapconn.SendRequest(getUserRequest);

SearchResultEntryCollection Users = Response.Entries;
```

This may not be *exactly* what you need, but as you can see, you'll have a lot more flexibility to change and modify the search criteria. I use this code to search massive domain structures, and it's almost instantaneous, even with large amounts of users and groups.